# How to separate a real integer polynomial into two with real/complex roots?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

If the coefficients of a polynomial p(x) are all real integers, then every root of p(x) is either 1) real or 2) a complex number whose conjugate is also a root of p(x).

Is there any easy way to separate $p(x)\rightarrow p_1(x)p_2(x)$, where $p_1$ has only real roots and $p_2$ has only complex roots?  I understand that $p_1$ and $p_2$ will not generally have rational coefficients.

Comment: Check out http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20946/criteria-to-determine-whether-a-real-coefficient-polynomial-has-real-root for a start ...